# не работают стрелки клавиш в midnight commander linux

Tags: linux, mc

Не работают стрелки клавиш(на любых системах) в midnight commander linux вместо этого при нажатии пишет буквы либо ничего. Сервер достался от прошлого админа.

Проверял процессы/установленные пакеты на наличие красивого интерфейса по типу zsh. Переустановка MC.

Так же не корректно отображает htop(там каша вместо графики из символов[image: введите сюда описание изображения] из символов.

Comment: приложите к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]) вывод `$ echo $TERM`

Comment: и добавьте, каким терминалом в каком дистрибутиве пользуетесь

Comment: проблему решил.  в /etc/profile каким то образом подгружалась команда по типу color256.