# Расползаются данные htop, nload по экрану консоли в Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: ubuntu

Чистая Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS. Подключаюсь к серверу по ssh с помощью putty.
Установил nload и htop:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo install htop
sudo install nload
```

На экране консоли вижу следующую картину - значения "расползаются":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем кроется проблема. С теми же настройками подключения к тому же серверу, на котором были установлены и Ubuntu 16 и Ubuntu 20 таких проблем не было.

```
# echo $TERM
xterm
```

Comment: тот же вопрос и к вам: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1311999/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%88-%d0%b2-midnight-commander-linux#comment2315201_1311999

Comment: добавил. echo $TERM говорит "xterm"

Comment: в консоли набрал TERM=xterm-color, запустил htop - вроде нормально стало. Как теперь сохранить эту переменную и после перезагрузки сервера? Ситуация с nload - не исправилась - график не отображается.

Comment: переменная определяет характеристики используемого терминала, а чаще, как и в вашем случае - эмулятора терминала. следовательно, эмулятором терминала и должно устанавливаться её значение. вы упомянули, что в качестве эмулятора используете программу putty. вот её средствами и надо устанавливать нужное значение. я бы рекомендовал `xterm-256color`